# How to check multiple users then return all checked user using angular 4 and typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, angular4-forms

i want to display all employees then check the absents then return who are absents

This is my form :

```
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body" >
             <form [formGroup]="attendanceForm">
              <div class="row">
                <table class="table table-hover table-condensed text-center table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th> Names </th>
                        <th>  Attendance </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let attendance of attendances">
                       <td > {{attendance.Emp_Name}} </td>
                       <td> 
                           <div class="form-check">
                              <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input type="checkbox (change)="onChange(attendance.isAttend,$event.target.checked)" >{{attendance.isAttend}}
                               </label>
                             </div>
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
           </div>
           <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" (click)="onattendanceSave(attendanceForm.value)"> Save </button>
           </div>
        </form>
```

component.ts:

```
this.attendanceForm = this.fb.group({
        'isAttend' : this.fb.array([])
    })

onattendanceSave(form:NgForm){
console.log(this.attendanceForm.value);
        }
onChange(attendance:string, isChecked: boolean) {
    const attendanceFormArray = <FormArray>this.attendanceForm.controls.isAttend;

    if(isChecked) {
        attendanceFormArray.push(new FormControl(attendance));
    } else {
      let index = attendanceFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == attendance)
      attendanceFormArray.removeAt(index);
    }
}
```

I displayed all employees (attendance.Emp_Name) and next to each employee his checbox , if he is absent then i'll check it .. How can i return only checked employees using Angular 4 ? now isAttend logs null

Comment: How does your attendances array look like?

Comment: attendaces return all data of employees and i take only emp-Name to display it

Comment: Okay, your code looks a bit different, seems you are using some property `isAttend` as well in your code, but anyway, it should work... https://plnkr.co/edit/AmaZJEiNaHcoJkHz6KsX?p=preview

Comment: @AJT_82 Thank you it works :)